# kill a process running in the android emulator

Tags: android

How do I kill an application running in the emulator? I mean manually and not through code.

The Settings->Apps->Running tab does not display my application and Dev Tools->Running Processes lists my application but I don't see how to kill the process. I don't see any option in adb to kill a process either.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you want to kill without ddms :

Use this to list the processes and their pid's

```
adb shell ps
```

---

and go for the kill using

```
adb shell kill <PID>
```

Where `<PID>` is the Process you want to kill (int)

Comment: If you want to do this one step, and you know the process you want to kill, you can string the two together as such:

`adb shell ps | grep [your query here] | awk '{print $2}' | xargs adb shell kill`

Comment: Yarian, by default the Android emulator doesn't have grep, xargs or awk

Comment: @Richthofen The command line of "yarian" works because grep, xargs and awk commands are executed by your system shell and not by the Android Debug Bridge shell

Comment: I had to type ```adb root``` before I was able to kill the process

Comment: I get "operation not permitted"

Answer (score 28):

Go to DDMS and select your App process. Click STOP icon in upper-right-hand side. It will kill the process.

[image]