# process running in the android emulator not closed

Tags: android, process, android-emulator

My question is related to this question.
[kill a process running in the android emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8227726/kill-a-process-running-in-the-android-emulator)
Application is not closed in android emulator, will it behave similarly in actual device?
I am running background task(via service) which will be executed each time app started. Problem is application process is not closed even though onDestroy() is called. And I cannot start my background task, since it assumes that task is already run.

Answer (score 0):

To stop a service, you should not call `onDestroy` directly but either `stopService` from another context, on `stopSelf` from the service itself.

`OnDestroy` is hook provided by Android so that you can react to the system killing the service, but there is no real guarantee that this method will be called in all situations. For instance, if your service is killed as the system is under memory pressure, it won't be called.

Comment: Thanks, I know that onDestroy should not be called directly, while writing question I meant, onDestroy is called correctly by android system, not by me.

Comment: Is you service sticky ?

Comment: There is no problem with my services, main problem with application. I checked other demo apps from well known android libs, they're also not closed(process) after application termination.

Comment: What do you call termination ?

Comment: By terminatation I mean, correctly closed application: Exiting from application by clicking back button as much as needed and onDestroy() called correctly by OS.

Comment: My pleasure. And how do you see a process remains alive ?

Comment: from DDMS and in emulator with Dev Settings, which shows current working processes

Comment: That's very strange. But if that is really a problem, you should reformulate your question and give all required details at once, with screenshots of ddms, top, etc. Sorry not to be able to help more.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38461/discussion-between-user1831986-and-snicolas)